# How can I download a lot of videos from YouTube simulteneously?

Tags: youtube, multiprocessing, pytube, aiogram

I use [Pytube](https://github.com/pytube/pytube) to download videos from YouTube.

This library is completely synchronous, and of course it can take a very long time to download a video.

I call the following code from an asynchronous [aiogram](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram) message handler.

```
    video = YouTube('url')
    video = video.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
    video_path = audio.download()
```

I have to speed up this process as much as possible even if a video is long.

I'm thinking of using the concurrent library and its ProcessPoolExecutor to download videos from processes. Would this be a good idea?

Perhaps you know of any other tools to install many videos at the same time, given that they can be 2+ hours long?

Comment: Just to make sure: you are trying to download a lot of video once and for all, correct ? How many videos do you mean by "a lot" and do these videos are published on a YouTube channel that you own ?

Comment: Videos will be installed by users requests, respectively, while the program itself is alive. In addition, there may be many users and a user may request a long video. Each video from a user is downloaded once and, after it has been received by a user, is no longer stored in our file system.

Comment: I don't know much of PyTube but I had a good experience of [yt-dlp](https://pypi.org/project/yt-dlp/).